# Simulate a web browser engine from .Net code

Tags: c#, .net, browser, simulate

I would like to be able to simulate a browser engine from my code to retrieve a web page from a specific link, and parse the data, the problem is that the page contains some Ajax calls and all I can get is the source code before any script is running.

Is there an easy way to get the final page from the code after the?

I'm currently using the following code:

```
//create the constructor with post type and few data
MyWebRequest myRequest = new MyWebRequest("https://www.kayak.com/flights/LHR-AMS/2014-09-10/2014-10-15");
//show the response string on the console screen.
Response.Write(myRequest.GetResponse());



public class MyWebRequest
{
    private WebRequest request;
    private Stream dataStream;
    private string status;

    public String Status
    {
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
        set
        {
            status = value;
        }
    }

    public MyWebRequest(string url)
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.

        request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    }

    public MyWebRequest(string url, string method)
        : this(url)
    {

        if (method.Equals("GET") || method.Equals("POST"))
        {
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = method;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Method Type");
        }
    }

    public MyWebRequest(string url, string method, string data)
        : this(url, method)
    {

        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = data;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        // Get the request stream.
        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();

    }

    public string GetResponse()
    {
        // Get the original response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        this.Status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;

        // Get the stream containing all content returned by the requested server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        // Read the content fully up to the end.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

Comment: Problem is you would need to execute the JS code yourself. On your position I would hack a bit and use a WebBrowser control that would open the page with the IE engine and even execute the JS. After a while you can fetch the final HTML code.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about going in this direction, I'll try it and post results.